# Decompose complex types in JS

Tags: polkadot-js, extrinsic, api

My overall goal is to build a generic extrinsic builder, just like the extrinsic tab from `polkadot-js/apps`. This code is very old and very hard to decipher unfortunately and I couldn't find any doc for this.

The UI lists all the pallets and their methods. The next step is to show all the arguments for each method, with JS/TS types corresponding to the Rust types.

I'm taking a very specific type as an example and we can go from there.

The `democracy.vote` call takes the following arguments

- `{ name: "refIndex", type: "Compact<u32>", typeName: "ReferendumIndex" }`
  this translates to an integer.
- `{ name: "vote", type: "PalletDemocracyVoteAccountVote", typeName: "AccountVote" }`
  this is more complex and is the reason why I post here.

Here is how I get this:

```js
import { getTypeDef } from '@polkadot/types/create'

const arg = api.tx["democracy"]["vote"].meta.args[1]
const argTypeDef = getTypeDef(arg.type)
console.log('argTypeDef', argTypeDef)
// { name: "vote", type: "PalletDemocracyVoteAccountVote", typeName: "AccountVote" }
```

Now, under the hood, this type `AccountVote` is an enum as seen in the [rust doc](https://docs.rs/pallet-democracy/latest/pallet_democracy/enum.AccountVote.html). It has other nested types such as `Vote` and `Conviction`

How would you go about coming from the `AccountVote` to have something incrementally translated into JS, which is what I could pass the the api to construct this call?

```js
{
    Standard {
        vote: {
          aye: boolean,
          conviction: string
        },
        balance: string,
    },
    Split {
        aye: string,
        nay: string,
    },
}
```

The closest I came is to create an instance of this type, but it initializes it with the defaults so we're missing part of the information.

```js
const instance = argTypeDef.type && api.registry.createType(argTypeDef.type)
console.log(instance.toHuman())
// {
//  "Standard": {
//    "vote": {
//      "conviction": "None",
//      "vote": "Nay"
//    },
//    "balance": "0"
//  }
//}
```

Comment: cool, is it going to be open-source?

Comment: Of course, just like 99% of what I build.